# Complex Potentials, Potentials and Fields

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, complex-numbers

Suppose an electric field $E=-\nabla \psi$ where $\psi=-Q\ln r$  where $Q$ is just some constant and I have found its harmonic conjugate to be $-Q\theta+c$ where $c$ is some constant. What does it say about the field? I know that if I calculate the field directly from $E=-\nabla \psi$, I get $E=Q/r$ pointing radially outwards, but I am not sure how to interpret the harmonic conjugate found (is it even right?).

***Update:*** I believe I have figured this out now. All the correct information follows from the Cauchy-Riemann equations!

Comment: Your potential looks like the potential of an infinite line charge. So E does not point radially outwards but cylindrically outward.

Comment: @Revo, yes, you are right, of course :) I was working in 2D.

Comment: @charge: It would be great if you can post your answer.

Answer (score 3):

It gives you an E field which looks like the B field around a current carrying wire.  You can think of it as being the solution from a "magnetic current" at the origin.  Of course, it is not a single valued function, which has interesting implications I'm sure someone else will elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

If you lay the potential equal to constant, you get equipotential lines.

If you do the same for harmonic conjugate, you get lines that are always perpendicular to the equipotential lines, thus "streamlines" of E.
You can read about hydromechanical analogy in this article (although there's a mistaken sign in the Cauchy-Riemann equations): https://www.siam.org/students/siuro/vol1issue2/S01010.pdf